# File Upload destination folder best practice

Tags: angular, file-upload

I have an Angular2 application that use a .NET WebApi to generate text files.

The files, once created, must be downloadable from the application.

I need to know what are the best practices to store the generated files and how to reference them in the application.

In this moment I have created a folder called `upload` under the `assets` system folder because a friend of mine suggested this but is this the best method?

I'm new to Angular2 and I don't know what assets folder is best for.

I also think that I will have to exclude this folder in `.gitignore`.

Comment: I notice now that using assets folder is not a good Idea, because each time I upload a file, the rebuild starts...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is just a general list of good practices to follow for any type of file upload to an internal server - Remember you are allowing outside files inside the sanitized zone.

1. Always restrict the type of files that can be uploaded.

   This can be done through client side validation (preferable) or server side. My applications do both, as the client side can be manipulated.You should also check for added on extensions like somefile.bmp.exe.
2. Limit the file size that can be uploaded.
   for my backup application I split the files in order to maintain the file size limit
3. Keep the target upload folder outside of your web servers root folder.
4. Invest in a good anti virus program and scan that folder continuously
5. Always rename the uploaded files.

   One of my applications I save the original file name and path in my filesUpload database (to restore backups), but the file in the upload folder is always renamed.
6. For sensitive data you should encrypt the file once its uploaded